# Why do values of :db.type/uri return as com.cognitect.transit.impl.URIImpl?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm working with Datomic Cloud and I noticed the following scenario, whenever I transact a fact that is of the `java.net.URI` type and try to query it back I get `com.cognitect.transit.impl.URIImpl` back as the type, I was expecting that the types remain the same.  I have found no documentation about this or how to deal with it.

This breaks behavior where I am using interop to, for example, get the host of a URI.  As Clojure will throw an exception `No matching field found: getHost for class com.cognitect.transit.impl.URIImpl`.

This issue **does not occur** in local-dev.

Example:

```clj
(require '[datomic.client.api :as d])

(def schema [{:db/ident :test/url
              :db/valueType :db.type/uri
              :db/unique :db.unique/identity
              :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
              :db/doc "The URL."}])

(def cfg {:server-type :cloud
          :region ""
          :system ""
          :endpoint ""})

(def client (d/client cfg))

(d/create-database client {:db-name "test"})

(def conn (d/connect client {:db-name "test"}))

(d/transact conn {:tx-data schema})

(d/transact conn {:tx-data [{:test/url (java.net.URI. "https://www.google.com")}]})

(let [q '[:find ?url
          :where [?e :test/url ?url]]
      db (d/db conn)]
  (d/q q db))
;; => [[#object[com.cognitect.transit.impl.URIImpl 0x938b85 "https://www.google.com"]]]

(let [q '[:find ?url
          :where [?e :test/url ?url]]
      db (d/db conn)]
  (type (ffirst (d/q q db))))
;; => com.cognitect.transit.impl.URIImpl

(let [q '[:find ?url
          :where [?e :test/url ?url]]
      db (d/db conn)]
  (.getHost (ffirst (d/q q db))))
;; => Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
;;    No matching field found: getHost for class com.cognitect.transit.impl.URIImpl
```

I was expecting `java.net.URI` as the type.

<s>**UPDATE**: Jaret Binford from Datomic Support clarified that this is a potential bug on the Datomic end. I'll update the question once further clarification comes.</s>

**UPDATE**: Jaret Binford from Datomic Support confirmed that this is a bug on the Datomic end.

Comment: Relying on the concrete types in a dynamic language is probably asking for trouble... generally the better question is "does this thing have the schema I expect?" or "does the thing respond to this message?"

Comment: @JaredSmith as per the question, looks like the issue is the fake URI doesn’t implement getHost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We released a fix for this in Datomic Local 1.0.277, client-pro 1.0.78, and client-cloud 1.0.125.

Cheers!
-Jaret